# Tokenfield for Bootstrap with Twitter Typeahead shows object in suggestions instead of value

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, twitter-typeahead, bootstrap-tokenfield

I am using tokenfield for bootstrap with twitter typeahead and I am able to this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtFbj.png

I want only value to be displayed.

Here is my JS:

```
var engine = new Bloodhound({
        local: bloodhound_tag_data,
        datumTokenizer: function(d) {
            return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value);
        },
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
    });
    engine.initialize();
    $('#id_tags').tokenfield({
        typeahead: [null, { source: engine.ttAdapter() }]
    });
```

'bloodhound_tag_data' is a list of objects with 'id' and 'value' keys.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. In your code try replacing `typeahead: [null, { source: engine.ttAdapter() }]` with the following:

```
typeahead: [null, {
   display: 'value',
   source: engine.ttAdapter()
}]
```

This resolved it in my case where I observed something very similar to your screenshot.

Some background: The documentation for the `display` option of [typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#datasets) appears a little hard to understand for less experienced people like myself. It says (words that I think are relevant in bold):

> For a given suggestion, determines the string representation of it.
>   This will be used when setting the value of the input control after a
>   suggestion is selected. Can be either a **key string** or a function that
>   transforms a suggestion object into a string. Defaults to stringifying
>   the suggestion.

In this case `'value'` is the key into the field of one of the elements in array `bloodhound_tag_data`.

Happy coding!

If anything in my answer can be improved please add a comment with constructive suggestions. Thank you!